# Правильная ли логика в setter java?

Tags: java, maven, junit

Есть домашнее задание:

- Требования к работе с радиостанциями:
- Номер текущей радиостанции изменяется в пределах от 0 до 9
- Если текущая радиостанция - 9 и клиент нажал на кнопку next (следующая) на пульте, то текущей должна стать 0-ая
- Если текущая радиостанция - 0 и клиент нажал на кнопку prev (предыдущая) на пульте, то текущей должна стать 9-ая:

Код по переключению следующей станции:

```
 public int setNextStation(int nextStation) {
        int currentStation = this.getCurrentStation();
        if (nextStation == maxStation) {
            return minStation;
        }
        this.currentStation++;
        return currentStation++;
```

По переключению предыдущей:

```
 public int setPrevStation(int currentStation) {
        int prevStation = this.currentStation;
        if (prevStation == minStation) {
            return maxStation;
        }
        this.currentStation--;
        return currentStation--;
    }
```

Я выполнила тесты, они делаю 100% покрытия в Junit, не выполняются проверки граничных значений. При переключении вперед с 9 станции тест выдает 0 станцию (правильно), при назад на 0 станции выдает 0(хотя должен 9). Логика в коде одинаковая, но один тест не срабатывает.Сам тест на переключение предыдущей станции:

```
 public void prevStationThrowMaxStation() {
        Radio radio = new Radio();
        radio.setCurrentStation(0);
        radio.setPrevStation(0);
        assertEquals(0, radio.getPrevStation())
```

Comment: Вы не меняете currentStation при граничных значения, только возвращаете числа 0 и 9 бесконечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы возвращаете значение, но не изменяете сам обьект (то есть при граничных условиях код после if блока не выполняеться, метод возвращает minStation/maxStation, но currentStation не меняеться)
PS В ваших методах по уменьшению и увеличению текущей станции не нужен параметр.

```
public int decrementCurrentStation() {
        if (this.currentStation == minStation) {
            this.currentStation = maxStation;
        } else
           --this.currentStation;
        return this.currentStation; 
}
```

А само понятие сеттера - это функция по установке значения в конкретную переменную; для вашей задачи сеттер установит в currentStation значение из переменной:

```
public int setCurrentStation(newStation) {
        this.currentStation = newStation;
}
```

Обычно в setter не добавляют дополнительной логики

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по условию, ваши методы next и prev просто включают предыдущий и следующий канал. В связи с этим непонятно, с какой целью эти методы принимают в аргументах интовое значение, ведь мы не переключаемся на указанный канал, а включаем следующий/предыдущий. Кроме того, ваши методы написаны некорреткно. Например, вы дважды вызываете инкремнт для currentStation в методе next  :

```
    this.currentStation++;
    return currentStation++;
```

Аналогичная прблема с методом prev. Таким образом метод увеличивает / уменьшает значение текущей станции на 2, а не на 1.

В общем попробуйте проще, например, так:

```
public class Radio {

    private int currentStation;
    
    private final int minStation, maxStation;

    public Radio(int currentStation, int minStation, int maxStation) {
        this.currentStation = currentStation;
        this.minStation = minStation;
        this.maxStation = maxStation;
    }

    public int prev () {
        currentStation = currentStation <= minStation ? maxStation : --currentStation;
        return currentStation;
    }

    public int next() {
        currentStation = currentStation >= maxStation ? minStation : ++currentStation;
        return currentStation;
    }
    
    public int getCurrentStation() {
        return currentStation;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я чуть код скорректировала   if (currentStation == maxStation) {
            return minStation;
        } else
            this.currentStation++;
        return this.currentStation;
    }. Все работает

Comment: @Alina так это тоже самое. вы просто тернарный оператор изменили на обычный условный оператор))

Comment: Я в точь-в-точь ваш писала, он чего-то не срабатывал в моем тесте( Вот м подкорректировала чуть))

Comment: @Alina а можно узнать в каком тесте?

Comment: Тест как в вопросе и есть аналогичный на проверку работы переключения следующей станции. Тесты составлены одинаково по логике, только сеттеры отличаются.